# Evaluation of IR approach without test collections

Tags: hypothesis-testing, information-retrieval

I am trying to evaluate an information retrieval approach. More specifically, it's a query expansion algorithm, based on topic distribution in retrieved documents.

I want to evaluate my approach using the world wide web. Since most (all?) evaluation approaches use a test collection, where the whole corpus is known, I am having a hard time to find an evaluation approach which works only on retrieved documents.

So, I am looking for information on this topic. Maybe a paper or a keyword?

Comment: Could you use a survey sampling approach, like in polling where the researchers don't have access to the entire population?

Comment: Did some research. Either a system based approach or a user based approach is necessary. The system based approach needs data, which contains relevance judgements. The user based approach needs people to judge your approach.